# Freezes when lid is closed on a Dell E6500

Tags: suspend

Installed 11.04 x64 on my Dell E6500 some time ago and it freezes sometimes when I close my laptop.

After some search I did following actions:

```
disabled Sync to VBlank in Compiz settings
switched off screen saver
```

But is still freezes. Last one happened few hours ago: I was able to move mouse, but that's it - I couldn't click anything.

I pressed CTRL-ALT-BACKSPACE and restarted X.

```
uname -a: Linux rgwork 2.6.38-11-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP 
Fri Jul 29 19:02:55 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`dmesg`, `X.org` and `dpkg -l` on [pastebin](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1jGhvPpLbu6vySY0K_2kNMxauC_es7hxGXIxMRK55vVM)

Update:
it just froze again. I can move my mouse, and I see that the cursor changes to when I move my mouse (probably when it's going over some textfield), but screen remains blank.

i tried to go to sleep mode and wake it back, but screen remained black.

new `X.org` log on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0ddSTqRc) and 
`dmesg` on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/aZjGAspc)

Comment: Do you have the system set to either sleep or hibernate upon closing the lid?  That will cause it to break.  You can set it to just blank the screen (or "Black the screen") and it will work correctly.  (I have the same model system you do)

Comment: It is set to "Black the screen". I tried to send the laptop to a standby mode by pressing Sleep buttons (Fn+F1) and it went to a sleep mode, then I woke it up but screen was still blank.

Comment: Do you have it set to turn off the monitor/screen after a while?  If so disable that, as the monitor/screen won't turn on again until a reboot.

Comment: Just freezed again. "Turn off monitor" is disabled. What I did: closed lid and left it for a while. Don't know what else can I tune...

Comment: Do you have nvidia or intel graphics ?

Comment: Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) GM45

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).